# Unable to download large no. of Pdf's from web

Tags: python, pandas, download

I am trying to download a large no. of pdf's online(4000+) using this code. The code works well for some files while for others(nearly half of them), The downloaded file is corrupted and I get the error : "File type HTML document (text/html) is not supported". Please suggest the changes I should make.

```
lis = pd.read_csv("/home/harshit/geography/equitylist.csv") # list of all equities on BSE
for i in lis["Security Code"]:
    link = "https://www.bseindia.com/bseplus/AnnualReport/"+str(i)+"/"+str(i)+"0318.pdf"
    r = requests.get(link) # getting and saving annual report
    row=lis.loc[lis['Security Code'] ==i]
    name = row.iloc[0]["Security Id"]
    with open("reports2018incog/"+name+".pdf",'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
            f.write(chunk)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: I suspect that the "corrupted" files are actually just HTML responses saying that link was not found.  Have you tried opening some of the corrupted files in a text editor or browser?

Comment: Another possibility is that the site is not allowing you to download such a large number of files in a short time. Inspecting the non-pdf files in a text editor should give you a clue about what’s happening.

Answer (score 1):

## Maybe the files are not pdf

Maybe some of the links are broken or return a redirect page or a 404 error page, because as the error suggests you're making a request for a pdf file and not really receiving one so i suggest you check if the file is a pdf.
1) Check the headers

```py
In [19]: page  = requests.get("https://www.adobe.com/support/products/enterprise/knowledgecenter/media/c4611_sample_explain.pdf")

In [20]: page.headers
Out[20]: {'Content-Type': 'application/pdf', 'Content-Length': '88226', 'Server': 'Apache', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=86400', 'Last-Modified': 'Wed, 05 Jan 2005 19:56:38 GMT', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'X-Adobe-Loc': 'uw2', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=21590', 'Expires': 'Wed, 23 Jan 2019 04:53:53 GMT', 'Date': 'Tue, 22 Jan 2019 22:54:03 GMT', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

In [21]: page.headers['Content-Type']
Out[21]: 'application/pdf'
```

So a simple if condition before saving the file would be a great way to start! So here is a revised code for the particular problem.

```py
lis = pd.read_csv("/home/harshit/geography/equitylist.csv") # list of all equities on BSE
for i in lis["Security Code"]:
    link = "https://www.bseindia.com/bseplus/AnnualReport/"+str(i)+"/"+str(i)+"0318.pdf"
    r = requests.get(link) # getting and saving annual report
    if r.headers['Content-type'] == "application/pdf":
        row=lis.loc[lis['Security Code'] ==i]
        name = row.iloc[0]["Security Id"]
        with open("reports2018incog/"+name+".pdf",'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
                f.write(chunk)
        time.sleep(2)
    else:
        print(f"Oops! Unable to process {link}")
```